# how put an image over embeded flash in asp.net pages - z-index not help

Tags: asp.net, flash, visual-studio-2010, z-index

my aspx codes :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Building.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Web Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bgstretcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/bgstretcher.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="OuterDiv">
        <div id="InnerDiv">
            <div id="Content">
                <div id="BMSFlashContainer">
    <object id="BMSFlash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="281" height="375" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="Flashes/BMS.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
    <embed name="BMSFlash" src="Flashes/BMS.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="281" height="375" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
                </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and css codes :

```
body
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
body, input, option, select
{
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'b yekan' , 'b homa' , 'Arial' , 'Verdana' , Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    background: #a099ff url('../Images/back.jpg') no-repeat scroll left top;
}
a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #0061B7;
}
a:hover, a:active
{
    color: #1BB2FD;
}
a img
{
    border: none;
}
.label
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
div#OuterDiv
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
div#InnerDiv
{
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent url('../Images/Blue.png') repeat scroll left top;
}
#LiveContainer
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
#imgLive
{
    width: 200px;
}
#BMSFlashContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

that embeded flash (BMSFlash) Is always over imgLive Image -> how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
<embed name="BMSFlash" src="Flashes/BMS.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="281" height="375" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

To:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed wmode="transparent" name="BMSFlash" src="Flashes/BMS.swf" quality="high"  width="281" height="375" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you're doing this with *large* SWFs you'll get quite a hit on performance. 281x375 will be fine though.